# Shuffle a dynamic array of returned strings

Tags: php, shuffle

Major PHP beginner here!! I want to get all images from a directory, exclude any non .jpg files, shuffle the results and then display the string. Eventually it will be merged into some sort of slideshow. Everything worked fine up until I tried to shuffle the results. I get no output, just a blank screen.

```
<?php
$rootpath = 'images/slide/';
$fileinfos = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootpath));
foreach($fileinfos as $pathnames => $fileinfo) {
shuffle($pathnames);
foreach ($pathnames as $pathname) {
    if (preg_match("/^.*\.(lck|bak|swf|mno|png|php)$/i", $pathname)) {
        } else {
            echo $pathname. "<br />";
                }
        }
}
```

?>

Solution!! Thanks for all the help, was making things a lot harder for myself.

```
<?php
$rootpath = 'images/slide/';
$pathnames = scandir($rootpath);
shuffle($pathnames);
foreach ($pathnames as $pathname) {
if (preg_match("/^.*\.(lck|bak|swf|mno|png|php)$/i", $pathname)) {
    } else {
        print_r($pathname);
         }
}
```

?>

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: If I remove the shuffle bit, I get this: images/slide/IMG_2747.JPG
images/slide/100_0547.JPG
images/slide/IMG_6039.JPG
images/slide/IMG_2188.JPG and so on.

Answer (score 1):

If $pathnames really is a string as you say, this is working perfectly. Visit http://writecodeonline.com/php/, paste the code below into the textarea, and hit "Run Code" multiple times. Notice how they are being randomized correctly.

There is something else going wrong...

```
$pathnames = "images/slide/IMG_2747.JPG images/slide/100_0547.JPG images/slide/IMG_6039.JPG images/slide/IMG_2188.JPG images/slide/IMG_1114.JPG images/slide/IMG_2135.JPG images/slide/IMG_8990.JPG images/slide/DSCN4634.JPG images/slide/IMG_0739.JPG images/slide/IMG_5145.JPG";
$splitpathnames = explode(" ", $pathnames);
shuffle($splitpathnames);
foreach ($splitpathnames as $pathname) {
if (!preg_match("/^.*\.(lck|bak|swf|mno|png|php)$/i", $pathname)) {

        echo $pathname. "<br />";
     }
 }
```

Comment: Still no shuffling occurs.

Comment: At this point, are you showing blank screen or unshuffled items? Also, are there numeric or alphanumeric keys?

Comment: Blank. It would seem my problem is that $pathnames is not an array. It is just a collection of string! LOL, told yall I was a beginner!

Comment: images/slide/IMG_2747.JPG images/slide/100_0547.JPG images/slide/IMG_6039.JPG images/slide/IMG_2188.JPG images/slide/IMG_1114.JPG images/slide/IMG_2135.JPG images/slide/IMG_8990.JPG images/slide/DSCN4634.JPG images/slide/IMG_0739.JPG images/slide/IMG_5145.JPG   etc.... seperated by a space

Comment: edited my response, try that - woops just edited again, make sure you have the most recent one when you try it

Comment: Returns a list of the files as before, no shuffling.

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(25) "images/slide/IMG_2747.JPG" } is the output right before the shuffle

Comment: Edited my response again. Maybe trying that will give you some insight.

Comment: Also for beginners, errors are hard to spot so paste an error handler from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_error.asp in the top of your page. Within the php tags of course lol. See "Testing the error handler by trying to output variable that does not exist:"

Comment: My problem was my array was not an array, it was just a string. Went scandir instead of a directory iterator. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Per your comments, $pathnames is not an array. You must first generate an array based on the strings and then shuffle it:

```
$pathnamesArray = explode(" ", $pathnames);
shuffle($pathnamesArray);
foreach ($pathnamesArray as $pathname) {        
    if (!preg_match("/^.*\.(lck|bak|swf|mno|png|php)$/i", $pathname)) {                  
         echo $pathname;
    }  
 }
```

Comment: What is the output of shuffle($pathnames); ie: `var_dump(shuffle($pathnames));exit;`

Comment: The output is: bool(false)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the $pathnames array prior to failure?

Comment: If I take the shuffle bit out: images/slide/IMG_2747.JPG
images/slide/100_0547.JPG
images/slide/IMG_6039.JPG
images/slide/IMG_2188.JPG
images/slide/IMG_1114.JPG
images/slide/IMG_2135.JPG
images/slide/IMG_8990.JPG
images/slide/DSCN4634.JPG
images/slide/IMG_0739.JPG
images/slide/IMG_5145.JPG

Comment: Err...LOL. What array keys? That is the exact output that I get.

Comment: what is the out put of this: `var_dump($pathnames);exit;` if you put it before the shuffle?

Comment: string(25) "images/slide/IMG_2747.JPG"

Comment: Oh...So could I convert the returned strings to an array?

Comment: Ok...now the output is: Array ( [0] => images/slide/IMG_2747.JPG ) Array ( [0] => images/slide/100_0547.JPG ) Array ( [0] => images/slide/IMG_6039.JPG ) etc...

Comment: that's not great. I'll update my answer to help you create a valid array

Comment: Thanks, went with scandir instead of running a directory iterator, Put it in an array, problem solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can sort an array representation of an object but not an object in itself since it has no order of attributes.Try this?

```
<?php
    $rootpath = 'images/slide/';
    $fileinfos = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootpath));

      foreach($fileinfos as $pathnames => $fileinfo) {
        if (!$fileinfo->isFile()) continue;
          if (preg_match("/^.*\.(lck|bak|swf|mno|png|php)$/i", $pathnames)) {
        } else {
                    $arr = (array)$pathnames;
                    shuffle($arr);

               foreach($arr as $pics){
                  print "<img src =  " . $pics . " />";
              }


           }

        }

?>
```

Comment: Nope, it displays the results as before, but no shuffling happens: images/slide/IMG_2747.JPGimages/slide/100_0547.JPGimages/slide/IMG_6039.JPG